# How to import a markdown file from github into local gitbook

Tags: github, markdown, gitbook

I try to import an .md file from a repo on github into my local gitbook.

I want to do something like this in my SUMMARY.md file:

```
# Summary

* [Introduction](README.md)

* [button-color](https://github.com/blah/button-color/blob/master/README.md)
```

In this case it becomes only a link.

How can I import the file?

I googled it but can't find any answer.

Is this even possible?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"it becomes only a link"_ Yes, that's because you're using the syntax for a link. What are you trying to do? Do you want to include the full contents of the `README.md` file hosted on GitHub in that list element?

Comment: I found out how to do it (check my answer) thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do it.

I created a `BUTTON-COLOR.md` file.

In the file I needed this line:

```
{% include "git+https://github.com/blah/button-color.git/README.md" %}
```

In `SUMMARY.md` i Just added the reference to `BUTTON-COLOR.md`:

```
# Summary

* [Introduction](README.md)

* [button-color](BUTTON-COLOR.md)
```

Comment: How to import from a tag of different repo